# Alguna libreria que sustituya a <windows.h> de C en Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Cree una funcion en C para centrar texto, pero el unico problema que tengo es que me arroja fatal error a la hora de compilar con la libreria windows.h, la cual es indipensable para este programa ya que las funciones y keywords que necesito solo estan ahi. A mis amigos que trabajan en Windows les funciona perfecto pero a mi no, deduzco que es porque uso Linux.
Solo quiero saber si puedo sustituir dicha libreria por una que tambien me sirva en mi sistema operativo, o si definitivamente no existe una alternativa. Gracias :)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    void gotoxy(int,int);
    void Centrar_Texto(const char *texto,int y);

    int main()
    {   
        Centrar_Texto("Hola Mundo\n",0);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }                           

    void gotoxy(int x, int y){
        HANDLE Manipulador;
        COORD Coordenadas;
        Manipulador = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        Coordenadas.X = x;
        Coordenadas.Y = y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(Manipulador,Coordenadas);
    }

    void Centrar_Texto(const char *texto,int y){
        int size_texto = strlen(texto);
        gotoxy(40-(size_texto\2),y); printf("%s",texto);
    }
```

Comment: El problema es que estas usando una API que es de Windows,  Todo el código de  `gotoxy` es totalmente dependiente de Windows y no va funcionar de ninguna forma en Linux, por que es imposible compilarlo.  Además, conceptualmente el acceso a la pantalla de texto, es muy diferente en ambos sistemas operativos. Si quieres hacer algo parecido, te sugiero que inestigues por el lado de https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te paso el link de una pregunta muy similar.
Básicamente el problema radica en que estamos hablando de dos sistemas operativos distintos, los cuales manejan sus respectivas APIs, por lo que no es posible hacer uso de las funciones que brinda la librería windows.h en un entorno Linux

Link del post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317523/what-should-i-use-instead-of-windows-h-in-linux

Comment: Lo que corresponde es reportar la pregunta para que sea cerrada por duplicada, o dejar un comentario al OP.

Comment: @CandidMoe No se puede marcar una pregunta como duplicada de una pregunta en ingles...

Comment: @gbianchi. Sin embargo, respuestas en inglés son aceptadas ...

Comment: @CandidMoe para nada.. por favor, señalamela y la borramos... Hay una discusion respecto a otro tema en meta, pero la respuesta no esta aceptada y esta siendo discutida...

Comment: @gbianchi. Tengo problemas para logearme en chat. Me corrigo. Donde dice "son aceptadas" debe decir "no son rechazadas".

Comment: pero son rechazadas.. @CandidMoe.. hay solo un caso que esta en discusion... todo el resto, se pide traduccion o se borran....

Answer (score 0):

En Linux, puedes utilizar la biblioteca `<unistd.h>` para llamadas al sistema y las bibliotecas `<sys/types.h>` y `<sys/stat.h>` para operaciones de archivos. Además, puede utilizar la biblioteca `<pthread.h>` para subprocesos múltiples y la biblioteca `<ncurses.h>` para interfaces de usuario basadas en consola. Estas bibliotecas proporcionan una funcionalidad similar a `<windows.h>` en Windows.

De todos modos, para por ejemplo, definir la función `gotoxy` en Linux podrías hacerlo de siguiente manera:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", y, x);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Este módulo puede servir tanto para Windows como para Linux.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    COORD coord = {x, y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
#else
#include <stdio.h>
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", y, x);
    fflush(stdout);
}
#endif
```